# two-tier angular/sails Error: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'

Tags: angularjs, cors, sails.js, gulp

I am setting up a two-tier angular/sails app based on this tutorial: http://www.pluralsight.com/courses/two-tier-enterprise-app-api-development-angular-sails . For development my backend/sails server is localhost:1337, my frontend/angular server is localhost:8000. The frontend is a gulp-webserver with proxy configured for all API requests to go to sails. I was under the impression this would mitigate any need for special angular routes to satisfy CORS issues. However, when clicking a link that is supposed to open a twitter auth window I get a blank screen and in chrome dev I am seeing:

`XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize?oauth_token=oPMDYAAafAAAAhT6lTlwk. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8000' is therefore not allowed access.`

I have read the documentation for sails on CORS and allowed CORS for * for now.
http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/security/cors

**Sails CORS config:**

```
module.exports.cors = {
  allRoutes: true,
  origin: '*',
  credentials: true,
  methods: 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD',
  // headers: 'content-type'
};
```

**gulp-webserver proxy config:**

```
gulp.task('serve', ['copyAll'], function() {
  return gulp.src(paths.temp)
  .pipe(webserver({
    livereload: true,
    proxies: [{
      source:'/api',
      target:'http://localhost:1337'
    }]
  }));
});
```

**Angularjs Controller:**

```
angular.module('app', ['satellizer'])
  .config(function ($authProvider) {
    $authProvider.twitter({
      url: '/api/user/login'
    });
  });
```

**Response Headers:**

```
access-control-allow-credentials:true
access-control-allow-origin:http://127.0.0.1:8000
connection:keep-alive
content-length:113
content-type:text/plain; charset=UTF-8
date:Mon, 07 Sep 2015 18:36:14 GMT
location:https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize?oauth_token=7A8gtyfhgghfyuAhaeEAAABT6kWRtw
vary:X-HTTP-Method-Override, Accept
x-powered-by:Sails <sailsjs.org>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Could this be an issue with how I am communicating with the twitter API?

Comment: Yes, your sails method seems to redirect your client to twitter, which it won't allow you to do front end (hence the cors message). How are you calling twitter in sails?

Comment: From my UserController... here's the gist: https://gist.github.com/CiscoKidxx/bd7b4a01edfc55ec9e09

Comment: @Jorg - I am using the request library and making a POST from the UserController on the backend. Here's the http://gist.github.com/CiscoKidxx/bd7b4a01edfc55ec9e09

Comment: I found the problem but it's so incredibly unrelated I think I might just delete the question.

Answer (score 1):

The issue ended up being related to the satellizer dependency. When I was following the tutorial I installed the newest version and there were some significant changes. If you are following the tutorial, make sure to install "satellizer": "~0.8.7"!

After correcting that everything magically worked. Hope this saves someone some time!